# Netcating from client to server with docker-ed application lags initially

Tags: ip, docker, lag, latency, netcat

I have a client and server in an en enterprise environment. `netcat`ing client to server is instant.

```
     _______SERVER______                     ______CLIENT_______ 
    |                   |                   |                   |
    |                   |    <--------->    |                   |
    |    20.20.20.20    |                   |                   |
    |___________________|                   |___________________|

    > netcat -l 8000                 
                                            > netcat 20.20.20.20 8000
    blahblah                                blahblah
```

However netcating with a container on the server..

```
     _______SERVER______                     ______CLIENT_______ 
    |                   |                   |                   |
    |   __container__   |                   |                   |
    |  |             |  |    <--------->    |                   |
    |  | 30.00.00.01 |  |                   |                   |
    |  |_____________|  |                   |                   |
    |                   |                   |                   |
    |    20.20.20.20    |                   |                   |
    |___________________|                   |___________________|

    > docker run -p 8000:8000 -t -i ubuntu netcat -l 8000

                                            >netcat 20.20.20.20 8000
    (blank for 10 seconds)                  blahblah
    blahblah
    blah2                                   blah2
```

So the difference is that the first message takes about 10 seconds to appear when I use `netcat` inside a container. Why is this? After that the messages are instant.

Since `netcat`ing without a container is instant I am pretty sure there's something tricky going on with docker.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved this issue. Using the `-n flag` makes it all work nice. So instead of

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -t -i ubuntu netcat -l 8000
```

you use

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -n -t -i ubuntu netcat -l 8000
```

According to Docker the `-n` flag is to

> Enable networking for this container

I am still puzzled though how networking works even without it. What does it **actually** do?